# Update NSOpenGLView size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, opengl

I want to update my NSOpenGLView window when texture size is changed. Thats OK. I register event when that happens, but I can't resize OpenGLView. Value witch is being changed is `w` and `h`.

```
-(void)initOpenGL {
NSSize size = {w, h};
[self setFrameSize:size];
NSOpenGLContext *glcontext;
glcontext = [self openGLContext];
[glcontext makeCurrentContext];
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);               
glOrtho(0.0, h, 0.0, w, -1.0, 10.0); 
}
```

When application starts it works OK, but when I do `[self initOpenGL]` after any of these size changed, OpenGL view is getting black, and not working any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will meet this problem just add `glLoadIdentity();` at the beginning of OpenGL initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call `[glcontext update]` and `glViewport(0,0,oglWidth,oglHeight)` to adjust for the change in view size.

Comment: I tried it. Maby I don't know how to use it but in function witch is runned when sizes changes i add `[glcontext update]`, but nothing.

Comment: Doesn't works as it should work. I guess its because glOrtho is described at program launching and is not edited later on when resizing. But as I see I can't update glOrtho. If it now resize nearly OK, I mean it sets width as it should, but height stays as it was at launchtime and its viewing only a part of texture witch was stetted at launch time. I mean, glOrtho is the problem

Comment: Actually i now can recall `initOpenGL`. I just needed to add `    glLoadIdentity();` at openGL initialization. Thank you for help. Maby you know how to set my NSOpenGLView position that it would always be vertically aligned to center?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a NSOpenGLView, then there's a method called `reshape` which gets called when the view is being reshaped.  There, you should call `glViewport` and update the size accordingly.